# How to obtain dropdown item value from a form and pass to controller in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

Given something like below,

```
@{  
    if (IsPost){
         var someValue = Request.Form["item"];
        }
}

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header">Items</li>
          @foreach (var item in @Model)
          {
            <li><a href="#" name="item" id="selectedItem">@item</a></li>
          }  
      </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem that occurs is the data is not being passed to the controller for the `selectedItem`.

For example,

```
public ActionResult Index(string item){

return View();
}
```

`item` returns null, so the value is not being passed it seems. How do I pass information from the View to the Controller in a form that contains a dropdown. Essentially, I would like to have the dropdown item selected passed to a controller.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the HTML helpers (Html.DropDownListFor) and binding to it? If you did so this would naturally pass back to the controller. Your ViewModel would possibly need to be altered to contain a SelectList of the items that need to be displayed in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` links trigger `GET` requests, not `POST` requests, so your `this.Request.Form` will always be empty.

Use the querystring. Values are accessed by `this.Request.QueryString`:

```
@foreach(var item in @Model) {
    <li><a href="?item=@item">@item</a></li>
}
```